# Telegram bot not responding to message handler

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere, telebot

I wrote a bot on polling, now I am remaking it on webhook and flask, pythonanywhere. How to make the bot react to the message handler
I have a large bot project already running. but it works in polling mode.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import telebot

# BOT TOKEN
bot = telebot.TeleBot("6181772972:AAH2ai1yQjJKyNkpsj924tPwOrkXRDWYuu8")

# Make flask object
app = Flask(__name__)

# set webhook
@app.route('/hook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook_handler():
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode('utf-8'))
    bot.process_new_updates([update])

    message = update.message

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "responce test")

    return 'ok'

# /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
   
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "start command")

# random text
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


# start  Flask
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set webhook`your text`
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url='https://manov.pythonanywhere.com/hook')
    # run app Flask
    app.run()
```

Comment: You should not post your token publicly, redact it out.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `if __name__ == "__main__"` is not run when you run your code  as a web app on PythonAnywhere, so you will need to move the webhook stuff out of that block